# how to limit typeorm join queries?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm new to typeorm, maybe someone can resolve my problem.
I'm using NestJS and TypeORM and have two tables (categories and talents). I wish to find a solution to limit typeorm join queries.

each category can have many talents in `talent_worked` and each talent can have many categories in `working_categories`.
i like to find all categories and there respected talent but i wish to get(limit) only five talents.

**Talent**:

```js
@Entity('talents')
@Unique(['mobile'])
export class TalentsEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    name: string;
    
    @Column({ unique: true })
    mobile: string;
    
    @Column({ nullable: true })
    email: string;
    
    @Column({ select: false })
    password: string;
    
    @Column({ select: false })
    salt: string;
    
    @Column({ default: false })
    isBlocked: boolean;

    @Column({ default: true })    
    isActive: boolean;

    // relation to categories model
    @ManyToMany(
        type => CategoriesEntity,
        categoriesEntity => categoriesEntity.talent_worked,
        { eager: true },
    )
    @JoinTable({ name: 'talents_working_categories' })
    working_categories: CategoriesEntity[];
}
```

**Category**:

```js
@Entity('categories')
@Unique(['title'])
export class CategoriesEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    title: string;

    // relation to talents
    @ManyToMany(
        type => TalentsEntity,
        talentsEntity => talentsEntity.working_categories,
        { eager: false },
    )
    talent_worked: TalentsEntity[];

}
```

**here is my typeorm query so far**:

```js
const query = await this.createQueryBuilder('category');
query.leftJoinAndSelect('category.talent_worked', 'talent');
query.leftJoinAndSelect('talent.working_categories', 'talentCategories');
query.where('talent.isActive = :isActive AND talent.isBlocked = :isBlocked', { isActive: true, isBlocked: false});
if (categoryId) query.andWhere('category.id = :categoryId', { categoryId });
query.select([
    'category.id',
    'category.title',
    'talent.id',
    'talent.name',
    'talentCategories.id',
    'talentCategories.title',
]);
query.orderBy('category.created_at', 'ASC');
query.addOrderBy('talent.created_at', 'ASC');
return await query.getMany();
```

Comment: hello, did you managed to solve your problem?

Comment: no, do you have any solution?

Comment: did you try using `.take(n)` instead of `.limit(n)` ? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68468192/difference-between-limit-and-take-in-typeorm

Comment: you helped me a lot to solve this problem!

Comment: By using what @AntonyGibbs suggested you might have a bunch of unnecessary data loaded in RAM just to be throw afterward. Does not sounds so cool to me. Read the ref Antony Gibbs mentioned.