# Typeorm / Postgres: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list

Tags: sql, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have the following entities: **User** and **Role**.
I want to select users with their roles with pagination and filters.

**Error message:**

```
for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in the select list
```

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class User {
  *******

  @ManyToMany(() => Role, (role) => role.id, {
    nullable: true,
    cascade: true,
  })
  @JoinTable()
  roles: Role[];

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Role {
  @Field((type) => Int)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  title: UserRoles;

  @Column()
  description: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

**Main query logic:**

```
******
    const [results, total] = **await queryBuilder
      .orderBy(`"user_${sortField}"`, sortOrder)
      .take(limit)
      .skip((page - 1) * limit)
      .leftJoinAndSelect('user.roles', 'role')
      .getManyAndCount();**

    return {
      results,
      total,
    };
```

It leads to error because in generated SQL line **SELECT DISTINCT
"distinctAlias"."user_id" as "ids_user_id"** doesn't contain a field user_updatedAt which im ordering by.

**Note**,.take(limit) method adds the above-mentioned line is generated SQL and I can't find a way to edit selected fields.

**Generated SQL:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   \"distinctAlias\".\"user_id\" as \"ids_user_id\" 
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         \"user\".\"id\" AS \"user_id\",
         \"user\".\"firstName\" AS \"user_firstName\",
         \"user\".\"lastName\" AS \"user_lastName\",
         \"user\".\"email\" AS \"user_email\",
         \"user\".\"phone\" AS \"user_phone\",
         \"user\".\"isActivated\" AS \"user_isActivated\",
         \"user\".\"refreshToken\" AS \"user_refreshToken\",
         \"user\".\"createdAt\" AS \"user_createdAt\",
         \"user\".\"updatedAt\" AS \"user_updatedAt\",
         \"role\".\"id\" AS \"role_id\",
         \"role\".\"title\" AS \"role_title\",
         \"role\".\"description\" AS \"role_description\",
         \"role\".\"createdAt\" AS \"role_createdAt\",
         \"role\".\"updatedAt\" AS \"role_updatedAt\" 
      FROM
         \"user\" \"user\" 
         LEFT JOIN
            \"user_roles_role\" \"user_role\" 
            ON \"user_role\".\"userId\" = \"user\".\"id\" 
         LEFT JOIN
            \"role\" \"role\" 
            ON \"role\".\"id\" = \"user_role\".\"roleId\"
   )
   \"distinctAlias\" 
ORDER BY
   \"user_updatedAt\" DESC,
   \"user_id\" ASC LIMIT 10"
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: The error is pretty clear - only the fields in the SELECT DISTINCT expression can appear in the ORDER BY expression. ORDER BY is applied after `SELECT`, at which point there's no `updatedAt`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PG::Error: SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693089/pgerror-select-distinct-order-by-expressions-must-appear-in-select-list)

Comment: I understand the theory but playing with it still can not find a correct solution to the following code:
    const [results, total] = await queryBuilder

      .orderBy(`"user_${sortField}"`, sortOrder)

      .leftJoinAndSelect('user.roles', 'role')

      .take(limit)
      .skip((page - 1) * limit)
      .getManyAndCount();

Any idea how could I change it to resolve the issue?

I don't understand why Typeorm adding these fields \"distinctAlias\".\"user_id\" as \"ids_user_id\" to the SELECT DISTINCT only?

Answer (score 2):

This suggestion helped to solve the problem:
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4742#issuecomment-783857414

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.offset()` and `.limit()` instead of `.skip()` and `.take()`
it worked for me.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69440654/13991708) answer for explanation.